# Javascript - Search unicode string in unicode string

Tags: javascript, string, search, unicode

When i try to search a unicode string in a unicode string, i find no solution.

Ex: check if string `'vie'` is contained in string `'Mr. ViỆt has a blue house'`

So i try a hard way as below:

```
// Convert string to Unicode
function toUnicode(theString) {
  var unicodeString = '';
  for (var i=0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }
    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  }
  return unicodeString;
}

// Convert string to be Regex Unicode
function toRegexUnicode(theString) {
  var unicodeString = '';
  for (var i=0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }
    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  }
  return new RegExp('[' + unicodeString + ']')
}

// Search
function searchUnicode() {
    var strOriginal = "Mr. ViỆt has a blue house"
    var regexUnicode = toRegexUnicode(strOriginal)
    var strSearch = toUnicode('vie')
    var result = regexUnicode.test(strSearch)
    console.log(result)
}
```

Test at: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FY3NGXMQRMLA

Are there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

First, your regex expression is wrong. Remove the braces.

Second, you're creating your regex testing the wrong way around.
You're currently setting up your regex search using your full string.
You're also not converting your `strOriginal` to Unicode.
This means your `searchUnicode` function needs to appear as follows:

```
var strOriginal = "Mr. ViỆt has a blue house"
var strOriginalUnicode = toUnicode(strOriginal)
var strSearch = toUnicode('vie')
var regexUnicode = toRegexUnicode(strSearch)
var result = regexUnicode.test(strOriginalUnicode)
```

Next, we can simplify your `toRegexUnicode` function as such:

```
// Convert string to be Regex Unicode
function toRegexUnicode(theString) {
  theString = theString.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")
  return new RegExp(theString)
}
```

No need to reuse your conversion method. You will also note global replacements of all `\` to become `\\`. That's because Regex considers a backslash as an escape character so we need to escape our escape character.

Answer (score 0):

I try another way, just convert all string to ASCII then search:

```
function stringToASCII(str) {
  try {
    return str.replace(/[àáảãạâầấẩẫậăằắẳẵặ]/g, 'a')
      .replace(/[èéẻẽẹêềếểễệ]/g, 'e')
      .replace(/[đ]/g, 'd')
      .replace(/[ìíỉĩị]/g, 'i')
      .replace(/[òóỏõọôồốổỗộơờớởỡợ]/g, 'o')
      .replace(/[ùúủũụưừứửữự]/g, 'u')
      .replace(/[ỳýỷỹỵ]/g, 'y')
  } catch {
    return ''
  }
}

function searchASCII() {
  var strOriginal = "Mr. ViỆt lê nguyễn thị tùng á à ạds"
  var strSearch = "vie"

  var strOriginalToASCII = stringToASCII(strOriginal.toLowerCase())
  var strSearchToASCII = stringToASCII(strSearch.toLowerCase())
  var result = strOriginalToASCII.includes(strSearchToASCII)

  // Results
  console.log('strOriginalToASCII: ', strOriginalToASCII)
  console.log('strSearchToASCII: ', strSearchToASCII)
  console.log('result: ', result)
}
```

Output:

```
strOriginalToASCII: mr. viet le nguyen thi tung a a ads
strSearchToASCII: vie
result: true
```

Test at: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FY3NGXMQRMLA